# Trying to receive value from Mongoose Database returns undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to get a password attribute from a Mongoose Database that I created to store users. I can get the username just fine, but when I try and use this to get the password:

```
User.find({ 'credentials.username': gusername }, function(err, user) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(user);
console.log(user.credentials.password);
});
```

It logs this in the console:

```
Connected to the DB using Mongo!
GET /login 200 66.097 ms - 1931
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.212 ms - -
drew
[ { credentials: { password: 'tueresputa99', username: 'drew' },
__v: 0,
_id: 569e5e99e7810411003c4c25 } ]
/home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/index.js:127
console.log(user.credentials.password);
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/index.js:127:33)
at    /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177    :19
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So as you can see, it successfully logs 'user', and you can see the password and username RIGHT there, but yet, I cannot get the password with `user.credentials.password`

Any help is appreciated! This is very frustrating :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` inside of `callback` function is an array rather than an object. Notice JSON array square bracket before user object
`-> [ <- { credentials:`

If your purpose is to find exactly one user you should use `User.findOne` function.

See this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne

Comment: So, I would have to use `User.findOne({ 'credentials.username': gusername }, function(err, user) {` , and then I could use `user.credentials.password`?